# Bitbucket - push a new projet to my bitbucket repo

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-push

I have the folder in my htdocs and I want to push it to an empty bitbucket repo.

So far I've followed the instructions on bitbuket website

```
git init
git remote add origin https://andradebuddha@bitbucket.org/musica.git


cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote add origin https://andradebuddha@bitbucket.org/musica.git
git push -u origin --all # pushes up the repo and for the first time
```

But And I'm getting this error

```
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
Everything up-to-date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved - I've missed a step.

```
git add -A # to add the brand new folders structure
```

And

```
git commit -m 'inicio do projeto'
```

and finaly

```
git push -u origin all
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the branch as indicated in the error message.

instead of `git push -u origin --all` try `git push origin master`